# Android Material Design- ActionBar and Title visible even after setting windowActionBar as false and windowNoTitle as true

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles

I am trying out the material design. I created a theme `MyMaterialTheme` in the styles.

**Styles:**

```
<resources>
    <!-- Theme for the material design of the app -->
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base"></style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryApp</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkApp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentApp</item>

    </style>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I included this theme (`MyMaterialTheme`). I can confirm that my theme is applied as it has taken the correct colors from it. I had assigned windowActionBar as false and windowNoTitle as true, but still I am seeing the ActionBar and the title when I run the app. Could anyone point out where I am going wrong?

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
           <!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Here is the screenshot of the emulator:**

[image]

Comment: These codes are duplicate in your styles btw: `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

Comment: @LinX64 Thanks for the comment. You mean the items in the AppTheme.NoActionBar?

Comment: That's like the default example from android studio, this one: `<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` i think you should delete them.by the way, i've tried this one : `android:windowNoTitle` and that didn't work.Unless, you'll have to use java like : `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: Can you show your layout xml code? Android Studio's default layouts will typically have a toolbar manually added to each layout, even if your app theme says there is none

Comment: @TheoKanning thanks a lot. You are right. Just saw my activity_main.xml, it had a toolbar and by default, the mainActivity.java had set it. After removing it, it is gone.

Comment: Great! I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your activity_main.xml file. Android Studio's default layouts will typically have a toolbar manually added to each layout, even if your app theme says there is none.

Comment: Thanks a ton. You are right. It was included in the activity_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

your base style that your material style extend it should be noTitlebar like this code

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```